# Generate NuGet on build when different intermediate directory specified

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I had a class library (.Net framework 4.8 that was generated with old csproj format, I've migrated it into new csproj format, following this: https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/.

The library uses custom property sheets to define the `<OutputPath>` tag to build the .dll to specific folder and uses `<IntermediateOutputPath>` and `<BaseIntermediateOutputPath>` tags to output the intermediate files into a different folder.
For example the debug tags look similar to this.

```
<OutputPath>c:\outputfolder\bin\debug</OutputPath>

<IntermediateOutputPath>c:\intermediatefolder\debug\</IntermediateOutputPath>
<BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(IntermediateOutputPath)</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
```

This works perfectly fine and I can see that dlls are in output directory and intermediate files are placed in intermediate directory.
The issue stems is that when Autogenerate NuGet on build is activated; the packing fails with this error

```
error NU5026: The file 'c:\outputfolder\bin\debug\ClassLibrary.pdb' to be packed was not found on disk.
```

This makes sense as the .pdb file is not located within output directory but within the intermediate directory. I’ve search around but I couldn’t find any options within VS where you can change the definition. Is there a way to do this, or do I have to create nuspec and manually pack it using NuGet CLI?

Comment: The pdb file actually exists under `c:\outputfolder\bin\debug\net48\ClassLibrary.pdb`, you can check it. And from your description, it seems that you want to pack the pdb file in the nuget package.

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT, Sorry I haven't been in the office yet. I will update you once I'm in back in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Generate NuGet on build when different intermediate directory
> specified

**Actually**, the `ClassLibrary.pdb` file exists under `c:\outputfolder\bin\debug\net48` folder and you can find it in your path.

And you do not have to use nuspec file with nuget cli, you could write in the xxx.csproj file directly to get what you want.

The below is what I did in `xxx.csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
    <OutputPath>c:\outputfolder\bin\debug</OutputPath>
    <BaseOutputPath>c:\intermediatefolder\</BaseOutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>c:\intermediatefolder\debug\</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(IntermediateOutputPath)</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>  //generate the nupkg during build process automatically
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(OutputPath)ClassLibrary.pdb" Pack="true" PackagePath="lib\$(TargetFramework)"></None>
  </ItemGroup>
  
</Project>
```

**Besides**, since you find that pdb file under `IntermediateOutputPath` folder, you can also use this to pack the file if you cannot find it in the `outputfolder` folder:

```
 <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)ClassLibrary.pdb" Pack="true" PackagePath="lib\$(TargetFramework)"></None>
 </ItemGroup>
```

======================

**Update 1**

Perhaps you have defined a property called `<CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory>false</CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory>` on the head of the `xxx.csproj` file or in a file called `Directory.Build.props` on the parent directory of the project folder, it will prevent the project generating the `xxx.pdb` file. If so, you should delete that node.

**In my side**, I defined that node in my `xxx.csproj` file and it will cause that behavior as you described.

[image]

So the suggestion is that delete that node or change the value of it to `true`.

```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
      <PropertyGroup>
    
    //delete this node or just change its value to true

<CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory>false</CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory> 
      </PropertyGroup>
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
        
      </PropertyGroup>
    
      <PropertyGroup>
        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>  
      </PropertyGroup>
    
    
      <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="$(OutputPath)test_3.pdb" Pack="true" PackagePath="lib\$(TargetFramework)"></None>
      </ItemGroup>
      
    </Project>
```

**Then**, when you change it, remember to close VS instance, delete `outputfolder` and `intermediatefolder` folders and then restart your project.

**Besides**, or you could delete the include xml node of xxx.pdb file if you do not want to pack it. The error happens because you want to pack it. If you want to exlclude the pdb file from pack, you can just delete that node.

```
<ItemGroup>
            <None Include="$(OutputPath)ClassLibrary.pdb" Pack="true" PackagePath="lib\$(TargetFramework)"></None>
</ItemGroup>
```

If you want to pack it, follow my above steps.

===============================

**Update 2**

After a deep research, I found that the `dotnet pack`(for new sdk format project) cannot work well with

```
<CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory>false</CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory>
```

It seems that no matter how you pull the `pdb` file from `intermediatefolder`, it always search the `pdb`file from output folder under `dotnet pack`.

**Solution**

**1)** If you still want to use `dotnet pack`(my method) and you are able to change `CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory` property, you should set

`<CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory>true</CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory>`

when you pack your project and when you create such nuget package, you can change it back if your build process needs it.

**2)** [Use nuget.exe with nuespec file to pack the project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package).

**First**,delete any related packing xml nodes in `xxx.csproj` file.

a) enter the path of your project folder where `xxx.csproj` file exists.

b) run `cd xxx(the path of your project)` on CMD

c) then run `nuget spec` to create the nuspec file:

d) write these in the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>test</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>me</title>
    <authors>me</authors>
    <owners>me</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://LICENSE_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://PROJECT_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://ICON_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>123</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2020</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
  </metadata>

<files>
<file src="C:\intermediatefolder\Debug\net48\xxx.pdb" target="lib\net48"/>
</files>
</package>
```

then run `nuget pack` to generate the **nupkg** file.

Comment: I found out why the .pdb was not copying to output, that is because the propertysheet was inheriting was setting <CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory> to false.
I've also tried adding the None include tag with intermediate path to pick it up from there, but I get the same error as before as it tries to pick it up from the output directory.

Comment: Is there a way to exclude the output.pdb from being picked up?

Comment: Actually,  your `xxx.csproj` seems to pack the `xxx.pdb` file into the nuget package. If you want to exclude that pdb file, you can just delete that include node of xxx.pdb file.

Comment: Please check whether your parent directory of the project folder has a file called `Directory.Build.props` file or check on the head of your `xxx.csproj`, whether there is a property `<CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory>false</CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory>` in that file. If so, it cannot generate the xxx.pdb file. And when you pack it, it cannot be found. So you should delete that node.

Comment: As I said in previous comment it was due to CopyOutputSymbols - switching this to true will solve the issue. Is there a way in the csproj to pack the symbol from intermediate dir rather than output. I don't have any XML nodes in regards to packing in my csproj, by default it tries to pick up the OutputDir symbol. If I manually add one but point it towards intermediate path the error still occurs (because it tries to pick up the output dir symbol too). I've also tried adding the node and setting Pack="false" but that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: After a deep research, I found that `dotnet pack` cannot work well with `<CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory>false</CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory>CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory>` no matter how you include the pdb file from  `IntermediateOutputPath` folder. Quite strange. Or you could set it to `true` if you are able to change it.

Comment: Besides, you could use nuget.exe with nuspec file to pack the project with the pdb file from `intermediatefolder` folder. First, you should delete any related xml nodes first in `xxx.csproj` file, then use my method from update 2. I have updated my answer. See update 2 and please check it. Please let us know if it helps or not.

Answer (score 0):

If your project output should not have PDB file at all and you want to use `dotnet pack` (same as package creation by Visual Studio) then you can add the following options to your project file to disable symbols generation at all.

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DebugType>None</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>
```